# PhoneGap fix width design

Tags: cordova, fixed-width

I'm working on my first PhoneGap project. I've received a fixed width design (640px). How can I tell make the same looking every screen. I've tried to force with meta like this:
`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=640, initial-scale=1, target-densitydpi=320" />`
But in AVD it wasn't good.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

[Reference1](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/viewport-metatag/)

[Reference2](http://mrbool.com/jquery-mobile-understanding-the-page-structure/26891)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use a special meta tag. You could use a responsive design which use percents insead of px:
intead of:

```
<img src="mount-mayon.jpg"  width:320px; margin-left:6px">
```

use

```
<img src="mount-mayon.jpg"  width:50%; margin-left:2rem">
```

That will make the same look in all screens. Use this meta with responsive design:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
```

The second option is the use of media tags. This makes changes acording to the screen and other parametres.

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 640px) {
.facet_sidebar {
display: none;
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: I want to make a non-responsive layout. I mean that on every device looks the same.

Comment: resposive design = lots of screen & same look <img src="mount-mayon.jpg"  width:50%;> means that the width will be 50% of the screen, wathever is the resolucion

Comment: Ok, I understand. But, I have a fixed 640 width design. What the solution on a larger screen? I mean there is 5 button in a row. 128px per button. If the app runs on a 800px width device the 20% width doesn't work...

Comment: Add width:100% to the body, html, page or what you are using: ej/ html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }